# Place a grey box around chart title in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

when we use the `facet` option in ggplot, we get a beautiful grey box around the headings (3,4,5).

```
library(ggplot2)

data(mtcars)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(cyl)) + geom_bar() + facet_wrap(~gear) + theme_bw()
```

How can we place a similiar grey box around the chart title when we do no use the `facet` option?

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(cyl)) + geom_bar() + theme_bw() +
  ggtitle("How do you put a grey box around me??")
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Since you are asking how to do it without facets, this is strictly speaking not an answer, but just to point it out, one quick and dirty way would be to "cheat" and to use a facet after all. For instance,

```
mtcars$title <- "How do you put a grey box around me??"
ggplot(mtcars, aes(cyl)) + geom_bar() + theme_bw() +
  facet_grid(. ~ title)
```

does the trick.

[image]

Comment: great cheat. will try to use that more often. :p

Answer (score 0):

you can use annotate and change plot title margin, then from annotate you can use "rect" geom for annotation:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = factor(cyl))) +
geom_bar() + 
theme_bw() + 
ggtitle("  How do you put a grey box around me??") +
theme(panel.grid = element_blank(),
panel.border = element_blank(),
axis.line.x = element_line(color = "black"),
axis.line.y = element_line(color = "black"),
plot.title = element_text(size = 12, color = "black", face = "bold", margin = margin(t = 10, b = -30)))+
annotate("rect",xmin=0,xmax=3,ymin=14,ymax=15,alpha=.2,color="black", linetype = 'dotted', fill = "grey1")
```

[Title with borders from annotate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RPQJb.jpg)

The other best and easy solution to save image as SVG then open it from inkscape 'free software' and then easily add rectangle to the title:

[Title grey box using inkscape](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cEugi.png)