# How to change the background color of the plot title in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, background-color, title

I am going to change the background color of the title which is plot by gglot2, making it look like using facet. Actually, it seems I could plot just using one facet. But are there any other parameters that could change the background color of a title of a plot?

Comment: Welcome to SO! What have you tried so far? To help us help you, please add a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: It's fairly easy to set the whole plot's background: `theme(plot.background = element_rect(fill = 'chartreuse'))` but just setting the background of the title will likely be a bit of work.

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37156845/3817004) shows how to place a grey box around chart title in ggplot2 by cheating with `facet_grid`. However, I understand that you are asking for other options, so your Q is _not_ a duplicate.

Comment: Currently this is an open issue on github - https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/2344