# Left align ggplot title (Tried hjust/margin() and nothing works)

Tags: r, ggplot2, alignment, margin, title

So I know there are a lot of posts out there regarding this question (I think I've read them all at this point). I've tried using hjust and margin() after learning hjust/vjust are hacks and nothing will work; no matter what I do the ggplot title remains center aligned. I need it left aligned. Is this possible? Does it have to do with the layout of my current code? Can someone please help?! Code is below. Thank you so much in advance! :)

Also, an aside to the above question, is it possible to place the title text inside a colored box? Like for example, white text embedded inside a black box?

Thanks again!

```
output$plot <- renderPlotly({
    if(input$Player == "")
      return(NULL)

    player_trend <- injury[injury$Player == input$Player, ]

    ggideal_point <- ggplot(player_trend) +
      geom_line(aes(x = Season, y = WAR), size = 1.25) +
      geom_point(aes(x = Season, y = WAR), size = 3) +
      labs(x = "Season", y = "WAR") +
      ggtitle("Title Goes Here") +
```

Comment: Right now the easiest way to left justify your title is to update ggplot. What you have looks like half of plotly plot (via Shiny), though. If `ggplotly` screw up your title, you'll have to go through plotly's functions.

Answer (score 2):

You provided no data nor a picture of what's wrong and possibly desired output and have actually asked multiple questions.

You're looking to do manipulations as the post-`ggplot2`-build grob level. That's some seriously low-level work.

This:

```
#' Completely flush-left-align ggplot2 title
#'
#' @return \code{gtable} object
#' @param gg ggplot2 object
title_left <- function(gg) {

  gt <- ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(gg))
  gt$layout[which(gt$layout$name == "title"), c("l", "r")] <- c(1, max(gt$layout$r))
  gt

}
```

flush-left (completely) aligns a title. It's no longer a `ggplot2` object and you need to use `grid` functions to draw it (like `grid::grid.newpage()` and `grid::grid.draw()`). If you want it less than completely flush-left you'll need to tweak the function.

For your over-reaching second question, you'd need to use something like this — https://stackoverflow.com/a/37156845/1457051 — and then change the above function to shift the facet title and rect grobs over (which I'm not going to do, but others here might do for you).

HOWEVER

You're not in `ggplot2`-land, you're in `shiny` and using `plotly` so this is all moot. Note that you *didn't actually tell us that* but `output$plot <- renderPlotly({` implies it. Your desire for interactivity is going (ironically) to limit your options. `plotly` is awesome for a quick interactive, but you'd spend less time making your own `htmlwidget` than you would trying to shoehorn a solution into `plotly` (though adding custom CSS for a targeted plot element could work but is also going to involve research).